# Multiple htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

here is my code for .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /display.php?page=$1 [L]
```

For the first one it works correctly and is displaying like this: 
`www.site.com/user`

The second one is not working, normally is displaying like this www.site.com/display.php?page=10. I want to display the page like this www.site.com/article
I tried different things and no result. Please tell me how to make to work with multiple rules. Also please give me an advice on how to use this functionalities in php because I think I done something not really good. My php code for using this rule is:

```
<p><a class="button" href="/<?php echo $user_data['username']; ?>"> Profile</a></p>
```

It works, but maybe is a better way to make a link to take advantage of htaccess.

Answer (score 32):

The two rules that you have conflict, the patterns used are *exactly the same*, which means, other than the conditions which only get applied to the first rule, the two rules are completely indistinguishable.

Given this URL:

```
http://www.site.com/blah
```

Is "`blah`" a page or a user? Can't tell, because the regex pattern (`^([a-z0-9]+)$`) for both rules matches "blah". So, the first one will always get applied *no matter what*. You need to add something to distinguish between the 2, like including a "user" or "page" in the URL:

```
http://www.site.com/user/blah
http://www.site.com/page/bleh
```

And your rules would look like:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)$ /display.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. I have two seperate pages and I was using same pattern and it was just using only one rewrite rule and I used your solution to distinguish using a prefix. I thought I needed two separate subfolders and separate htaccess for each subfolder which is a headache and didn't work for me due to using a htaccess in website root which was configured to remove php file extension.

Answer (score 10):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)$ /display.php?page=$1 [L]
```

use [N] (next) continue adding rules to the same condition
and [L] (last) to identify the last rule

Answer (score 4):

I made it working like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/index.php/$1 [C]

#second condition and rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/subdir/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

After a LOT of trial and error :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?\/)*?([a-z\.\-]+)(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest)$ $1$2$4 [NC]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The tip I received was that `[L]` denotes the last rule and `[N]` means continue.