# More than one rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to use like

```
www.site.com/somename
```

from two different pages. and i am using htaccess.

```
#1st condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

#2nd condition
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule (.+) clinicprofile.php?profilename=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works if i only use for one of above page condition, But when i use both conditions 404 page is showing.

Please try to solve my problem.

Comment: clinicprofile.php?profilename=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Did you enter that in browser address bar? :)

Comment: yes this is working... www.site.com/clinicprofile.php?profilename=somename

Comment: Check your (REQUEST_FILENAME) delimeters.

Comment: I think that is a typo  - it should be {}

Comment: Yes you are pointed out correctly, but still its redirected on 404 page, once i land on www.site.com/clinicprofile.php?profilename=somename page using www.site.com/somename

Comment: i am having similar problem, but couldn't find solution.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412302/multiple-htaccess-rewrite-rule

Comment: Read this today-asked question, It is 98% similar :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035624/mod-rewrite-two-rules-with-same-regexp-serve-first-or-second-if-404-raises-ak

Comment: thank you for this example question, i think same url "www.site.com/somename" for two different files is not possible, that will conflict it think. First condition can be possible but for the second one i need to use something like "www.site.com/clinic/somename".  ??

Comment: Yes ocourse! also chane the 2nd pattern to **^clinic/(.+)$** then both rules will work fine.

Comment: i have tried but still redirected me 404 and written on the page, "you have redirected loop", i am using RewriteRule ^clinic/(.+)$ /clinicprofile.php?action=clinic&profilename=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Do you have anyother rules in htaccess?

Comment: I got it. first was same but in second i used just you said to use clinic at start. But when i used that page was not displaying properly. so i put full url to every links (css, js, image) in page, and it worked.

Comment: yes, thats because the header base has changed for second rule ,and page was trying to load css,js images as /clinic/file.css. Another option to solve this is : adding the following in head of document **<base href="/">** this corrects the uri base.

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it so that it can help other users in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions,
what i have implemented is

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.+) profile.php?username=$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^clinic/(.+)$ /clinicprofile.php?profilename=$1 [L]
```

clinic word need to added.